# Imputing values for a categorical feature

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, classification, ensemble-learning, data-preprocessing

I have a categorical feature that takes calues ‘yes’ or ‘no’ and it has 50% missing values how can i impute missing values for this feature is there ant specefic way of imputing values for features with such high number of nan’s ?

Comment: "impute" depends on the context.  You could impute missing values to be the mode of this feature.  Do you want to?  Maybe.  It depends on the context.

Comment: @Him i have more than half of the values missing for this feature like 1,52,000 missing values out of 3,00,000 and this feature is inportant for my classification model i cant just drop is there any way i could impute then without using siple imputation methods ?

Comment: You could try replacing the term "impute" with "predict" in your thought process here and see what that gets you.  Will doing predictions using predicted features work out?  Probably you should have a way to answer that question.